# how do you pull data from two taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, tax-query

I have posts loaded from taxonomy, but I'm trying to get the data of another, that's also attached to the same post. In the code below, the main focus is getting `$location_slug`. Knowing how to get that I think I'd know how to get more data out of the second taxonomy.

```
// args for the term_query
    $sub_taxonomy = 'department_categories';
    $tax_args = array(
        'taxonomy'               => $sub_taxonomy,
        'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
        'order'                  => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'             => false,
    );

$the_query = new WP_Term_Query($tax_args );

// loop through the terms returned
foreach($the_query->get_terms() as $term){

    $term_id = $term->term_id;
    $term_name = $term->name;
    $term_slug = $term->slug;

    // args for the post query
    $post_type = 'career';

    $tax_query = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $sub_taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'id',
            'terms'    => $term_id,
            // 'operator' => 'IN',
        )
    );
    $post_args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'asc',
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'tax_query' => $tax_query
    );

    $primary_taxonomy = 'location_categories';
    $location = get_term( $term_id, $primary_taxonomy);
    $location_slug = $location->slug;

    query_posts( $post_args );

    $html_out .= '<h6>' . $term_name . '</h6>';

    $html_out .= '<div data-id="' . $location_slug . '" class="tab-pane fade in">';
            $html_out .= '<div>';
                $html_out .= '<div class="uncode_text_column">';

                // lopp through the posts
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

                    $product_title = get_the_title();
                    $product_link = get_the_permalink();

                    $html_out .= $product_title;

                endwhile; else: endif;

                $html_out .= '</div>';
            $html_out .= '</div>';
        $html_out .= '</div>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get all term slugs from the custom example taxonomy **space** by current post ID.

```
$space_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'space' );
if( $space_terms ) {
$space_terms = array();
  foreach( $space_terms as $term ) {
   $space_terms[] = $term->slug;
 }
```

}

You should specify the logical relationship between each inner taxonomy array when there is more than one.

The relation key in the array describes the relationship. Possible values are OR and AND.

```
'tax_query' => array(
'relation' => 'OR',
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'department_categories',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => $course_terms,
),
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'space',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => $space_terms,
 ),
),
```